# How to determine if a YouTube video is age restricted?

Tags: youtube

How does one determine if a YouTube video is age restricted?

Comment: fwiw, that only applies to shows, not to regular videos @pnuts

Answer (score 1):

1. Log out, use an incognito/private tab, or use an account whose user is <18 years old
2. Attempt to watch the video in question

If you can watch it without issue, it's not age restricted. If it prompts you to login to verify your age, it is age restricted.